# How to change the TimePicker Position?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, timepicker

I am using the jquery 1.6.4 for timePicker. TimePicker is working fine but i want to change the position of timePicker . Whenever i click in textBox to open timePicker it opens on right side which is outside the mobile app screen . So how can i change its position ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#sample1 input').ptTimeSelect();
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: This is the JavaScript which i am calling .
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
    
            $('#sample1 input').ptTimeSelect();
        });
    </script>

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for that

Comment: fiddle of what? I am just using that jquery and passing the id to that js.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ make a sample here, that what I meant

Comment: Examples on http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html are showing timepicker under select box...? You have to show more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change the position of textBox so that timePicker's position will be automatically changed .

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on JSFiddle and for me it's opening just below the text box.

http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/XNgWB/

But in case if this issue still persists, you can use containerClass attribute and define your css for the date dialog positioning.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#sample1").ptTimeSelect({containerClass:"test"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/sgbHk/1/

```
$.extend($.datepicker,{_checkOffset:function(inst,offset,isFixed){offset.top = 0;   offset.left=-100; return offset;}});
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#sample').datetimepicker();
});
```

You have to extend jQuery's datePicker default setup so the offset you set is in the `extend` function, just change the `offset.left`.

Comment: Thnx every one i have solved that issue after some changes in css.