# How to set display position to bootstrap-timepicker widget?

Tags: jquery, timepicker

Time picker show always bottom to text box. How to set position top?

```
$(".drop_timepicker").timepicker({
      showInputs: false,
      showMeridian: false        
 });
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14953349/492258) may give idea

Comment: Please try [this](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/issues/285#issuecomment-191671460)